# Using and Running Visual Basic on Mac

Tags: vb.net, macos, visual-studio, mono

This may seem like an absolutely stupid question, but it is one I really need to ask.

I *have* to find a way to be able to write and run a Visual Basic program on my Mac (Sierra). I have downloaded Visual Studio Community, and have even installed the [Mono Project for VB](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), although honestly I am not quite sure how to use it.

I need to be able to write the VB code and create an editable form to work with it. I will need to compile it and run it on Mac, but I do not have to turn it into an executable.

So, without Boot Camp or Parallels or anything like that, is there ANY way to get Visual Basic, as described above, to work on Mac Sierra?

Comment: Have you installed Monodevelop? From here you should be able to run your code and debug through this.

Comment: @Jaxi I have now installed Monodevelop, but I can't find a way to open a digital designer for the form. I am able to open the code, though. Am I actually able to create a form GUI I can use for VB?

Comment: WinForm isn't well supported for Mac OSX, since Mac OSX usually uses GTK+ for design. You can read here for any more info that you may need: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Comment: You can only perform .NET Core development in VB, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x and use Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit code on VS for Mac, but you can't run it. You should do bootcamp or VM Ware if you have a license for an extra copy of Windows.